# How to find out what function I am calling

Tags: python

I am calling a function like this:

`classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)`

and I would like to debug the code inside the `train()` function. The problem is that if I add `print` statements or `pdb` calls nothing changes.

I am importing this:

`from nltk.classify.naivebayes import NaiveBayesClassifier`

but even if I change something in `nltk/classify/naivebayes.py` nothing happens. I can also delete all the content of this file and I still have a working output. So I suppose that the function I am calling is somewhere else, but I cannot find it.

Is there a way to check where my function call is actually going? I am quite confused.

Comment: Add a print before your "classifier=" line and see if that still produces output, if not, trace back until you get output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step in the function using pdb.
use `pdb.set_trace()` some where before you are calling train method.

Something like this

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)`

When you debug. Stop at the line where you are calling train method.
press `s` to step in the function. This will take you inside the train function. From there you can debug normally.

Comment: Great, I think I got it. The function is calling the nltk implementation that I have on my system, and not the one that is in the actual folder that I am using. Do you have any suggestion about this? How can I use the module inside my current nltk folder instead of the one I have installed on my system?

Comment: Why don't you use virtualenvs to separate python modules on project basis. Virtualenvs acts like a sandbox. You can install whichever module you want in you sandbox using pip.

Here is a simple tutorial to get started: http://roundhere.net/journal/virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: I am not sure that I actually want to separate python modules on project basis. Since I am forking nltk, I want to make sure that when I write `import nltk` I am using the nltk code that I cloned from the repository (and not the nltk code that I have on my system). Is this related to virtualenvs?

Comment: I think virtual environment can help in such situation. Since you can make a new virtualenv it will not contain any of the python packages. You have to install the python packages that you need. So in this you can avoid installing nltk and use the once that you have forked.